# style="background-image not working but img is working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on AngulerJS project and following is not loading

```
<div class="fill" style="background-image:url('images/header_img1.png')"></div>
```

But with img tag is working.

```
<img src="images/header_img1.png" class="fill">
```

Do you have any idea why background-image is not working. Also I have noticed though img tag works there is no effect from fill class.

I'm just wandering is this because of Anguler JS?

Comment: try this `<div class="fill" style="background-image:url('~/images/header_img1.png')"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is with chrome(guessing you are using that browser).In that case remove the quotes around the url

```
<div class="fill" style="background-image:url(images/header_img1.png)"></div>
```

DEMO

```css
div {
  width: 153px;
  height: 230px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-image: url(http://freebigpictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/trees-forest-153x230.jpg)"></div>
```

Comment: im using firefox

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your div has no size at all. Try setting the size with `min-height` and `min-width`.

Also, could you add some screenshots of your inspected element?

```css
.fill {
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  background: #ccc no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="fill" style="background-image:url(https://media.giphy.com/media/nNxT5qXR02FOM/giphy.gif)"></div>
```

Comment: this is my fill. it seems style an class is not effecting.  .fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

Comment: Okay, I guess the problem is with `height: 100%` - is it filling out the 100% you want? You can check that by hovering over the HTML element in your inspection window. I suspect that your element has just 0px height.

Comment: backround-image is working when I'm not using Anuler-JS

Comment: Can you inspect your element and post the computed style?

Answer (score 0):

Check in the network tab for 404 response.

Try adding slash before image `/images/header_img1.png`, this work in case where the absolute url is http://localhost:3000/images/header_img1.png